# Cypress Test intercept normal method

Tags: angular, cypress, e2e-testing

I build a component with Angular 14 and this component uses an external service that provides user data (first name and last name). The service is imported as npm dependancy.

When implementing this service, we call its method get customer data and store the result in a variable that is used throughout our component.

The internal service looks like that:

```js
import { UserData, UserService } from 'externalService'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InternalService {
  
  private userData?: UserData;
  
  constructor(private userService: UserSerice) {}
  
  public async getUserData(): Promise<UserData> {
    this.userData = await firstValueFrom(this.userService.getProfileData();
    
    return this.userData;
  }
}
```

The internal Service an d its variable then is used in different components where user data is required.

Now I would like to e2e test this component in cypress. In order to cover multiple test scenarios, I created different fixtures, that include different user datas.

How can I mock the result of the getUserData()-method, to return my fixtures.

None of the methods calls an API endpoint or does any kind of network communication that might be intercepted. The future goal is, to fetch data from a redux store, which as WIP, atm.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike jasmine/karma, Cypress is a framework independent UI testing tool. This means it is not meant to stub actual services from angular. However, you can mock most of the browser behaviours. In this case, it will really depend on what your underlying `userService.getProfileData()` does.
If the `userService` fetches its data from the redux store, you should firstly dispatch the value you expect in your browser's store.

```
cy.window().then(win => {
  if (win.store) {
      win.store.dispatch(...));
  }
});
```

If your current service is a WIP and does not implement the redux store yet, you can always rely on another browser feature that you can prefill and read from, such as your localStorage. If you manage to get the `userService.getProfileData()` to read from your localStorage, you can then mock your expected output via the localStorage as following:

```
cy.window().then(win => {
   if (win.store) {
     win.localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');
   }
});
```

NB: you can easily embed local storage commands to Cypress via the [cypress-localstorage-commands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-localstorage-commands) NPM package, if you don't want to access the local storage maually.